# HTTP Error 403 with jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup, http-status-code-403

So I just started using jsoup on android, don't know much about it yet.
I'm trying to get content from website after submiting dropdown form.
Here's form code from [this](http://www.vzg.lt/pavadavimai/)website:

```
    <form action="" method="post" wtx-context="B0260501-E0B7-4F43-A196-9F51348D63C7"></form>
<table width="270" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr bgcolor="#F1F1F1">
      <td>
        <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr bgcolor="#F1F1F1">
              <td>
                <select name="metais" wtx-context="0AFA8447-4695-4215-8D1B-410F7EF474FC">
                  <option value="2018" selected="selected">2018</option>
                  <option value="2017">2017</option>
                </select>
              </td>
              <td>
                <select name="menuos" wtx-context="67952004-80BE-4E89-859A-3ADBC67FCD2F">
                  <option value="01" selected="selected">sausio</option>
                  <option value="02">vasario</option>
                  <option value="03">kovo</option>
                  <option value="04">balandžio</option>
                  <option value="05">gegužės</option>
                  <option value="06">birželio</option>
                  <option value="07">liepos</option>
                  <option value="08">rugpjūčio</option>
                  <option value="09">rugsėjo</option>
                  <option value="10">spalio</option>
                  <option value="11">lapkričio</option>
                  <option value="12">gruodžio</option>
                </select>
              </td>
              <td>
                <select name="dienas" wtx-context="8A955DD8-F426-4211-8CAA-133BD715D550">
                  <option value="01">01</option>
                  <option value="02">02</option>
                  <option value="03">03</option>
                  <option value="04">04</option>
                  <option value="05">05</option>
                  <option value="06">06</option>
                  <option value="07">07</option>
                  <option value="08" selected="selected">08</option>
                  <option value="09">09</option>
                  <option value="10">10</option>
                  <option value="11">11</option>
                  <option value="12">12</option>
                  <option value="13">13</option>
                  <option value="14">14</option>
                  <option value="15">15</option>
                  <option value="16">16</option>
                  <option value="17">17</option>
                  <option value="18">18</option>
                  <option value="19">19</option>
                  <option value="20">20</option>
                  <option value="21">21</option>
                  <option value="22">22</option>
                  <option value="23">23</option>
                  <option value="24">24</option>
                  <option value="25">25</option>
                  <option value="26">26</option>
                  <option value="27">27</option>
                  <option value="28">28</option>
                  <option value="29">29</option>
                  <option value="30">30</option>
                  <option value="31">31</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Rodyti" wtx-context="FA5C1EA9-B1BC-48A1-8079-FAD413B7BE09" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My Java code looks like this:

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(htmlPageUrl).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36")
                        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                        .execute();

                Document htmlDocument = Jsoup.connect(htmlPageUrl).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36")
                        .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
                        .data("metais", "2018")
                        .data("menuos", "01")
                        .data("dienas", "08")
                        .post();
                htmlContentInStringFormat = htmlDocument.select("div").first().text();
```

And I'm getting error

```
W/System.err: org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL=http://www.vzg.lt/pavadavimai/
```

This is request/response headers from that website

[image: chrome_dev_tools_network]

Why I cant access that website?
Also any suggestions on the code are also welcome (actually, I have a feeling that my code maybe not working as intended anyway, but still it shouldn't return 403 error i think).

Thanks

Comment: And the request headers your application is sending matches what you see in your browser?  (If the answer is "I dunno", that can be answered using tools like Wireshark.)

Comment: @JoeC Should I send all headers listed under "Accept:"?